# My object won't rotate and scale in the same time

Tags: c++, directx

I'm working to get my objects to rotate on my terrain.  Now here is my problem, I can rotate my object but not scale them or scale but not rotate.  It depends on which of my line of code goes last.  For example, If rotation code goes last it will rotate but not scale.

Here is my code

```
D3DXMatrixMultiply(&currentFrame->exCombinedTransformationMatrix, &currentFrame->TransformationMatrix, parentMatrix);
D3DXMatrixScaling(&currentFrame->exCombinedTransformationMatrix, trans.Sx, trans.Sy, trans.Sz);
D3DXMatrixRotationX(&currentFrame->exCombinedTransformationMatrix, D3DXToRadian(trans.Rx));
```

One of my buddies, Said that I'm overwriting the matrix.

So I tried this

```
D3DXMatrixMultiply(&currentFrame->exCombinedTransformationMatrix, &currentFrame->TransformationMatrix, parentMatrix);
D3DXMATRIX w;
D3DXMATRIX s;
D3DXMatrixScaling(&s, trans.Sx, trans.Sy, trans.Sz);
D3DXMatrixRotationX(&w, D3DXToRadian(trans.Rx));
D3DXMatrixMultiply(&currentFrame->exCombinedTransformationMatrix, &s, &w);
```

The result of the code above is now it will only scale no matter what.

Comment: Are you setting this exCombinedTransformationMatrix as the world matrix?

Comment: I wasn't but I gave it a try, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could try using D3DXMatrixTransformation or D3DXMatrixTransformation2D. These functions seem to take care of all the complexities (well at least the 2D one).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205365(v=vs.85).aspx
and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205366(v=vs.85).aspx